# Varnish keeps caching subdomains I ask it not to

Tags: varnish, cache

I'm trying to configure varnish not to cache any domain that begins with "staging" using the *pass* method like so:

```
if( req.url ~ "^(staging.)" )
```

I suspect I'm using VCL selectors wrong but after looking around on the n

Answer (score 4):

If you'd like Varnish "not to cache" and "not to look up in the cache", then the following should work...

```
# not to look up in the cache
sub vcl_recv {
  if( req.http.host ~ "^staging" ) {
    return( pass );
  }

  # other directives
}

# not to cache
sub vcl_fetch {
  if( req.http.host ~ "^staging" ) {
    return( hit_for_pass );
  }
}
```

For more info, checkout a [similar solution](https://www.varnish-software.com/static/book/VCL_Basics.html#solution-avoid-caching-a-page) from the official book on Varnish.

Answer (score 0):

`req.url` doesn't have that information.  Try using `req.http.Host` instead?

Comment: Tried that as well with:

   `if (req.http.Host ~ "^(staging.)^") {
        return (pass);
    }`

Still no luck.

Comment: @Will it should be `if (req.http.Host ~ "^(staging.)") { return (pass); }` . There is an extra `^` symbol in it. Please check my alternative answer to see if that helps!